# Redirect an Old Domain to a New Domain with HTTPS in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, server

Let's say we have, 
 Old Domain : `http://www.olddomain.com` 

New Domain : `https://www.newdomain.org`

Here's my .htaccess file data :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

Sometimes while redirection, browsers are displaying the Security error such that it is untrusted.

Now,

1. How to make this successfull ?
2. How to redirect this from non-www to www ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the order of your rules and clear your browser cache before you test it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Security error cleared ! But it's failing to convert non-www to www.

Comment: Perfect @anubhava  ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Perfect, I had accidentally kept 301 for temporary domain, browser cache was throwing ssl error, this solved issue